# From generalized eigen values problem to classical eigen values problem

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, diagonal, matrix-inverse

In Matlab, how could I convert, if possible, this solving of generalized eigen values problem :

```
[V,D,W] = EIG(A,B) also produces a full matrix W whose columns are the
    corresponding left eigenvectors so that `W'*A = D*W'*B eq(1)`.
```

Into the following classical problem, that is, to find a passing matrix `W` such that :

`A*W = D1*W` and `B*W = D2*W` where `D1` and `D2` coming directly from diagonlisation of `A` and `B` ??

I would have thought that multiplying (`eq 1`) on the right by `B^-1` would be enough but I wonder if I can conclude on a common basis for both matrices `A` and `B`.

If someone could give an advise, I would be grateful

Comment: How many columns should your 'passing matrix' W have? The same number of columns as A?

Comment: @dmuir . Thanks for your answer. Actually, I am working only on square matrices, so I consider in all of this 7x7 matrices. Why do you ask that ?